# Parsing multi-line string to extract only matched lines

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a multi-line string and I'd like to only extract lines that match a certain pattern and discard the rest of the string.

Original string:

```
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
nunc KEEP THIS LINE ut massa lorem
DO NOT KEEP THIS LINE aenean blandit
nunc KEEP THIS LINE et justo quis
praesent at velit felis vel
```

Desired final string:

```
KEEP THIS LINE ut massa lorem
KEEP THIS LINE et justo quis
```

The regex I have so far is:

```
(?ms).*?(?-s)^nunc (KEEP THIS LINE.*?$)
```

I can just replace the match with the backreference `\1`.  However, this fails to replace from the end of the last matched pattern to the end of the string.

The regex:

```
(?ms).*?(?-s)(^nunc (KEEP THIS LINE.*?$)|(?s:).*?\Z)
```

successfully identifies the pattern between the last desired line and the end of the string, but I can't figure out how to remove it.

Comment: You should always indicate which program you are using. There are almost always subtle differences between how two different programs implement regular expression, even if they're of the same "kind".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `^(?:nunc (KEEP THIS LINE.*)|.*\n)$` with `\1` will achieve the desired output:

- Due to the alternator (`|`), the expression `^(?:nunc (KEEP THIS LINE.*)?|.*\n)$` will forcefully match the entire line, without capturing it (`?:` designates a non-capturing group).
- If the line begins with `nunc KEEP THIS LINE`, `\1` will refer to the insides of the parentheses, i.e., the string beginning with `KEEP THIS LINE` and ending at the end of the line.
- If the line does **not** begins with `nunc KEEP THIS LINE`, `.*\n` will match the entire line, including the terminating newline character.

The above regular expression works fine with Perl.

In Notepad++ with Windows line breaks, you can use this one instead:

```
^(?:nunc (KEEP THIS LINE.*)|.*(\r\n)?)
```

Note that this will only remove the last line, not remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was using notepad++, which the documentation says is essentially the same as Perl, however the above solution did not work.  Everything mentioned above seems logical, I think it just fails for this specific implementation.  

The final regex that worked for me was the addition of the noncapturing symbol like you have:
(?s).*?(?-s)(?:^nunc (KEEP THIS LINE.*?$)|(?s:).*\Z)

Comment: There's a minor difference in how Perl and Notepad++ interpret the `$` character here, but the major problem is the operating systems' line terminators. Linux uses `\n` after every line (including the last one), Windows uses `\r\n` (not necessarily after the last one).